# php select data from database with join

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

i'm the sql statement below to select user's notes and the user they are following, this codes work if they are following another user:

```
$sql= "SELECT posts.* FROM  posts 
 JOIN(SELECT * FROM follows WHERE follower = '$get_user')follows
 ON follows.followe = posts.username OR  posts.username = follows.follower  GROUP BY posts.id";
```

i'll like to the function of the sql statement below to the one above in case they are not following any user.

```
SELECT * FROM posts where username = '$get_user'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` in place of `join`.
Left join will give you all the users irrespective of the fact that whether they follow a user or not. If they follow any user, you'll get corresponding values from the second table, and if not, the corresponding value (the second column) will contain null, indicating that none of the user has been followed.

Comment: it's not working , it fetching notes of user they are not following

Comment: Isn't this the same what you wanted? I interpreted it through these line of the question - `in case they are not following any user.` Please correct me if I misunderstood your statement.

Comment: @Yussuf Hassan i want it to fetch their notes only if they are not following any user

Comment: then use `a left join b on a.condition = b.condition where b.condition is null;` This'll give you (a minus b) i.e. all the entries that are in `a` but `not in b`. In this case, remember that you'll have to pick entries from `table a` in your select statement.

Comment: What's 'followe'?